# Why can't I do List<Item>?

Tags: c#, list, delegates

Am I missing some reference?

```
List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();
```

> The type or namespace name 'Item' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm new to using Lists and Delegates and stuff...

Comment: Yes, you are missing a reference to `Item`, as it says right there.

Comment: I have you declared your Item class? It is List<T> and T needs to be declared.

Comment: .. Do you have a class named Item in your code?

Comment: I think you're missing a using directive or an assembly reference..., this mean Item is in another project or namespace and you don't have the using reference to it. if you right click on it in visual studio there is the option to add the using statement, if it doesn't apper you have to add a reference to the library that contain the class Item

Comment: right Click on `Item` and see if you get `Resolve` in the menu, click that

Comment: What is `Item`, have you made a class somewhere in your application.

Comment: Also, if you do indeed have an Item class, make sure it's public if you're trying to use it : )

Comment: @Shane.C Although what you say is true, if that were the problem wouldn't the error say `The class 'Item' is not accessible due to its protection level`?

Comment: Oh.. I thought Item is something already defined like Object, etc... Thanks, everyone

Comment: @Nolonar You're right :) My bad.

Comment: @Adam Issues are "solved" when an answer is accepted. Don't just add "Solved" to the title.

Comment: @Nolonar Yeah I know, but it wouldn't let me accept an answer for another 7 minutes, and after that I just forgot. I just remembered though, so there we go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Item is a type that exists in your code / references, right click on it, open the "resolve" menu, and select the "using xx" option to add the correct namespace reference. Also, if Item is a type you're created, ensure it is visible to this class (might need to be scoped as public, if it isn't).

If Item doesn't exist - create it, add a reference to the dll containing it, or replace it with something that exists :)